# Why does 14.04 say there are no updates, when there are?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Why does Update Manager in 14.04 currently say it's up-to-date when `apt-get upgrade` shows there are updates to install?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's probably due to the [phased updates](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/phased-updates-to-start-rolling-out-for-ubuntu-13-04).

New updates may introduce new bugs.
So, to minimize the impact of those bugs, the updates are released gradually to more users.

This only affects the Update Manager, not *apt-get*.
If you run the Update Manager tomorrow, it will probably show some of those updates that *apt-get* is reporting now.

In short, I think it's normal.

**EDIT:** Yes, it's due to that. Check the Launchpad page of *evolution-data-server* in Trusty: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/evolution-data-server . There's a column for "Phased updates".